# slice a JSON object array with array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have the following snippet. I want to delete key value pairs using an array which has keys.

```
var fruits = [{ fruitId: B1, fruitName:"Banana", size : Medium}, { fruitId: B2, fruitName: "Orange", size : Big}, { fruitId: B3, fruitName: "Lemon", size: small}];
var fruitIds = [B1, B2];
```

Now I want to slice the fruits array after slicing it with fruitIds array. I want the result after slicing as

```
var fruits = [{ fruitName: "Lemon", size: small}];
```

I need it in pure Javascript.

Comment: Could you update your question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can utilize [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var fruits = [
  {
    fruitName : "Banana",
    size : 'Medium'
  }, 
  {
    fruitName : "Orange",
    size : 'Big'
  }, 
  {
    fruitName : "Lemon",
    size : 'small'
  }
];
var fruitNames = ['Banana', 'Orange'];

var result = fruits.filter(function (x) {
  return fruitNames.indexOf(x.fruitName) === -1;
});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

It outputs only `Lemon` since other two items are present in `fruitNames` array.

Comment: the fruits array and fruitNames array are formed dynamically. both the arrays may vary based on some other results.

Comment: @eaglemac Your objects should have some kind of "primary key property", which you will use for filtering. Otherwise, how would JS know how to filter objects.

Comment: Updated the question with ids which is the primary key.

Comment: @eaglemac Just change `fruitNames` to `fruitIds`, and `fruitNames.indexOf(x.fruitName) === -1;` with `fruitIds.indexOf(x.fruitId) === -1;`. What is the difference?

Comment: thanks. will this work when the fruits array and fruitids array change dynamically?

Comment: @eaglemac Of course. The first approach without IDs will work with dynamically added \ changed items perfectly, as well.